# POST /v3/conversations results in 403 BotNotInConversationRoster error

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

My chatbot needs to start a new converstaion/reply chain in a public Microsoft Teams channel. Unfortunately, I'm getting a 403 BotNotInConversationRoster error when sending a POST request to `/v3/conversations`.

My requests `POST /v3/conversations` (see [API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation)) looks as follows (note: I removed the access token):

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://smba.trafficmanager.net/de/v3/conversations -d '{"activity":{"text":"Test","type":"message"},"channelData":{"channel": {"id": "19:62fb45ddd8b2447082e5d1694ce8d735@thread.skype"}}}'
```

I don't understand the resulting error message.

```
{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."}
```

From my understand an installed chatbot with scope `team` should be a member of each public channel by default. Or am I missing something?

Any ideas/examples?

Comment: Is the Bot working in Teams at all?

Comment: Yes, works fine when I'm using the [Bot Builder sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/57.teams-conversation-bot).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be that the Bot registration in Azure doesn't have the Teams channel configured properly - see the image for reference[image]

Comment: I've used the App Studio for Microsoft Teams to create a bot. I thought doing so would configure the Azure part automatically as well.

Comment: No, App Studio just helps with the stuff needed -inside- of Teams - this is (kind of) outside of it. Add this channel setting (not to be confused with a "channel" in Teams), and check again. Even if this doesn't fix your current issue, it's absolutely required for the bot to work in Teams

Comment: I'm quite sure that the Azure part is configured by App Studio. But your were pointing me in the right direction. I've re-created the app with App Studio and everything works fine now. :)

Comment: When using the App Studio to create an app/bot, an Azure configuration is not required. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams#register-your-web-service-with-the-bot-framework for more information. However, I'm not quite sure if not using Azure Bot Service is a kind of legacy way to do it.

Comment: I'm going to do more research on this, as I don't think it's correct - I've posted a question on that page you linked to. Perhaps it's just historic. I'll let you know here if I find out anything - not impossible I'm wrong :-)

Comment: Ok, I see now - it's an option ONLY if you completely use App Studio to Create the Bot. I'm not sure I'd recommend doing that anyway, to be honest, because it binds your App Studio manifest a little bit too closely to your implementation. If you want to have, let's say, a Dev+Test+Prod version of your manifest, you'll want to have it version controlled as part of your code anyway, and controlled outside of the Teams client itself. Also, you might want to provision your bot another way (e.g. using Terraform) so once again you'll want to control. Finally, the bot might not be ONLY for Teams.

Comment: upvoted your comment as I learned something from this discussion - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To send bot notifications to the channels in ms teams, you should have install the bot app for team(not only for chat).
You can install your bot app to team either by

1. `Add app to team` manually in ms teams dashboard.
2. By using graph api, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http